# Using a few Wordpress upload form on a page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin. Using Wordpress' Upload System.
Basically this is my form inputs for upload :

```
<input id="upload_image" type="text" value="" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
```

Also other required js and css files enqueued (included). Lastly, this javascript included to page :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 // show Wordpress' uploader modal box
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 // this will execute automatically when a image uploaded and then clicked to 'insert to post' button
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 // put uploaded image's url to #upload_image
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

It's working very well, no problem. But now i want to add a few upload forms to page.

```
<input class="upload_image" type="text" value="" />
<input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />

<input id="upload_image" type="text" value="" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />

<input id="upload_image" type="text" value="" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
```

I've used `class="upload_image"` and `class="upload_image_button"` instead of `id="upload_image"` and `id="upload_image_button"`

Now i have to update my javascript codes.

Now there are a few upload buttons. BUt this isn't working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('.upload_image_button').prev().attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('.upload_image_button').prev().val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}
});
```

How should i update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var clicked = null;

jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
 clicked = jQuery(this);
 formfield = jQuery(this).prev('input').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 clicked.prev('input').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}
});
```